# Objective-C 101 (retain vs assign) NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsstring, retain

A 101 question

Let's say i'm making database of cars
and each car object is defined as:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Car:NSObject{
    NSString *name;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
```

Why is it `@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;` and not `@property(nonatomic, assign) NSString *name;`?

I understand that `assign` will not increment the reference counter as `retain` will do. But why use `retain`, since `name` is a member of the `todo` object the scope of it is to itself.

No other external function will modify it either.

Comment: But why?? Please add a reason!

Comment: Simple: an NSMutableString is an NSString. If someone passes you a mutable string which you retain, they can then change it afterwards. And since your property was NSString type, you likely aren't expecting that behavior.  By and large, immutable classes implement -copy by calling retain on themselves, so it's (usually) not costing you any memory unless you actually NEED that memory.

Comment: @ipmcc What about `readonly` properties (`@property (nonatomic, retain/assign/copy, readonly) NSString *myString;`), is it better to `retain`, `copy`, or `assign` those?

Comment: With a readonly property, retain/copy/assign makes no difference to external callers, but should still accurately reflect how you're treating the underlying value internally to your class. This is important if you're using ARC and @synthesize to create your iVars, as the compiler will use your property declaration as the indication of how you want ARC to handle that value when automatically handing retain/release.

Comment: @ipmcc: This is not entirely true. I would have to verify it again but IIRC if a readonly object property is assign, the getter just returns the value of the iVar, if it is retain or copy, the getter returns the value of the iVar as `[[... retain] autorelease]`, which can be an important difference if you ever replace the value of the iVar somehow in your code.

Comment: @RDC Why are you adding `ios` tag to questions that should be tagged only `objective-c`?

Answer (score 67):

There's no such thing as the "scope of an object" in Objective-C. Scope rules have nothing to do with an object's lifetime — the retain count is everything.

You usually need to claim ownership of your instance variables. See [the Objective-C memory management rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html). With a `retain` property, your property setter claims ownership of the new value and relinquishes ownership of the old one. With an `assign` property, the surrounding code has to do this, which is just as mess in terms of responsibilities and separation of concerns. The reason you would use an `assign` property is in a case where you can't retain the value (such as non-object types like BOOL or NSRect) or when retaining it would cause unwanted side effects.

Incidentally, in the case of an NSString, the correct kind of property is usually `copy`. That way it can't change out from under you if somebody passes in an NSMutableString (which is valid — it *is* a kind of NSString).

Comment: You should use copy instead of retain for all classes that has a mutable variant. Eg. NSAArray, NSSet, NSDictionary, NSData, NSCharacterSet, NSIndexSet, and NSString.

Comment: As a rule of thumb all properties with object references should use copy or retain, with one exception; delegates are assign to avoid circular references.

Comment: @Matt: Efreedom just has copies of SO questions, I'd suggest linking to the [original SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387959/nsstring-property-copy-or-retain) instead.

Comment: @PeyloW: Not just delegates; anything that is not an owning relationship should use `assign` rather than `copy` or `retain`. Paths down the object graph should be owning; paths up the graph (where included) should be non-owning. Otherwise, you will create circular references without having a delegate in the circle.

Comment: Technically, I wouldn't say there's no such thing as object lifetime scopes in Objective-C.  I would say the only scope-end is the autorelease pool's clean-up, which happens right in the main run loop and never in the middle of any Objective-C code.  But perhaps that's just a bit too technical. ;-)

Comment: @PeyloW: Why assign? why not weak? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html recommends using weak reference to avoid circular references.

Comment: @gmuhammad: This question was about retain vs. assign because strong and weak properties didn't exist in 2009. You're right that you would generally use *weak* these days.

Comment: @PeyloW, It looks like you're contradicting yourself. Should I use `copy` for classes with mutable variant or for __all__ objects?

Answer (score 19):

and don't forget to access it via

```
self.name = something;
```

because

```
name = something;
```

will not care about the generated setter/getter methods but instead assign the value directly.

Comment: Thanks, this was very important! Following the advice in the top answers was still not retaining the value. Very important to do `self.name = ...`

Answer (score 12):

Without `retain` there is no guarantee the `NSString*` you are setting `name` with will live any longer than the assignment statement itself. By using the `retain` property for the synthesized setter you're allowing it to tell the memory management system that there is at least one more object interested in keeping the `NSString*` around.

Comment: ok...yeah, I think I'm sorta geting you.
Please tell me in detail what you mean please.

Comment: because, if it's alive for the retain method, why not for the assign statement

Comment: The retain ensures that it will *stay* alive, whereas with assign, there is no guarantee of that.  Retaining means that you own that object and as long as you own it, it will not be destroyed.  Assign gives you no such guarantee.

Comment: Ahh, nice answer.

But then why not use it for other declarations such as for NSInteger types as well.

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSInteger *name;

Comment: @qstar: NSInteger is not an object.

Comment: Opps I meant
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSInteger modelID;

Let me restat my argument.

Why doesn't the same understanding apply for this case?

I see often @property(nonatomic, assign) NSInteger modelID;

Comment: Ahh, Thanks Chuck
So primitives are always held in memory!

Comment: Actually, why doesn't the same memory management concept apply to primitive values as well?

Comment: Some types (like NSInteger) are not heap-allocated, so there is no memory that needs to be released. Note that NSInteger is a different type from NSNumber, which does need memory management.

Comment: Whether it's allocated on the heap or not is beside the point. `malloc(sizeof(int))` allocates from the heap, but you'll crash if you try to release that. NSInteger is not an object and thus doesn't respond to messages.

Comment: What do you mean "no guarantee"?  Do you mean the memory can just go away on you randomly causing bugs?  Or do you mean if somebody did a [ release ] or [ dealloc ] on "the NSString* you are setting name with", then you would be s.o.l.?  ALso this is a separate question but a [ dealloc ] will completely destroy the NSString regardless of ref count, T/F?

Comment: @bobobobo: If you do not [retain] the `NSString*` it may be deallocated behind your back; your next dereference of it would be to undefined memory. [dealloc] should never be called from within your own code (other than to call [super dealloc] in your own [dealloc]) - all you should need to call is [retain] and [release], and the OS will call [dealloc] when appropriate.

Comment: Understandable answer.Then Can you tell me what is the difference between Copy and Retain

Answer (score 9):

For those who are looking for it, Apple's documentation on property attributes is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1).

Comment: That link is no longer available.

Answer (score 9):

The `self.` in:

```
self.name = something;
```

is important! Without it, you are accessing the variable directly and bypassing the setter.

The older style (correct me if I am wrong) would have been:

```
[self setName:something];
```

Anyway, this notation was the (vaguely familiar sounding) advice that I really needed when I went looking for proper `@properties` on `NSStrings`.  Thanks Axel.

Comment: this is a very nice info @jem. For the first time, I think it's too much (comparing with `this` in Java)

Answer (score 8):

After reading so many Articles, SO posts and made demo apps to check Variable property attributes, I decided to put all the attributes information together

1. atomic          //default
2. nonatomic
3. strong=retain       //default
4. weak= unsafe_unretained
5. retain
6. assign          //default
7. unsafe_unretained
8. copy
9. readonly
10. readwrite               //default

so below is the detailed article link where you can find above mentioned all attributes, that will defiantly help you.
Many thanks to all the people who give best answers here!!

> [**Variable property attributes or Modifiers in iOS**](http://rdcworld-iphone.blogspot.in/2012/12/variable-property-attributes-or.html)

1. **retain = strong**

   - it is retained, old value is released and it is assigned
   - retain specifies the new value should be sent -retain on assignment and the old value sent -release
   - retain is the same as strong.
   - apple says if you write retain it will auto converted/work like strong only.
   - methods like "alloc" include an implicit "retain"

Example:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;

@synthesize name;
```

2. **assign**

   - assign is the default and simply performs a variable assignment
   - assign is a property attribute that tells the compiler how to synthesize the property's setter implementation
   - I would use assign for C primitive properties and weak for weak references to Objective-C objects.

Example:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *address;

@synthesize address;
```

Answer (score 3):

Google's [Objective-C Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/objcguide.xml?showone=Setters_copy_NSStrings#Setters_copy_NSStrings) covers this pretty well:

> Setters taking an NSString, should always copy the string it accepts.
>   Never just retain the string. This avoids the caller changing it under you without your  knowledge. Don't assume that because you're accepting an NSString that it's not actually an NSMutableString.

Answer (score 2):

Would it be unfortunate if your class got this string object and it then disappeared out from under it? You know, like the second time your class mentions that object, it's been dealloc'ed by another object?

That's why you want to use the `retain` setter semantics.

Comment: Ok. So why would you ever *not* use `retain`?

Comment: If you're creating a .delegate property, the delegate will probably retain YOU. If you retain it back, you're creating a dependency loop that will result in neither object ever getting deallocated. Of course with ARC, this question is obsolete (we use "weak" and "strong" to imply something similar these days).

Comment: @DanRay neither object getting deallocated only if the Object B(had retained delegate of Object A) released in Object A's dealloc.