# iphone development controls null after ViewDidLoad

Tags: iphone

I am a newbie to both Iphone dev and obj c. I am trying to call a web service when the view is loaded and display a activity indicator during the time it takes to retrieve result from the web service.

My problem is that once the `ViewDidLoad` is completed, my `activityindicator` and labels are getting null. Hence after the web service call I am not able to manipulate any of the controls.

I am not able to understand why this is happening; obviously it is my lack of understanding of the basics. I done a bit of homework on this but I have not reached anywhere. It would very helpful if some could please explain why the controls get null once the `viewdidload` is complete.

Update: thank you for the answers. On `viewdidload`, I am doing the following, I am animating an activity indicator and assigning some values to my `textview`. Then I call a web service. Debugging the code, I realized that once `viewdidload` is complete and `-(void) connection: (NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)` is called, my text view/activityindicator gets null.

```
(void)viewDidLoad {
    [activityindicator startAnimating];

    if(myarray != NULL) {
        myuitextview.text = @""; // displaying some values from array
        @try{
            // call web service
        } @catch (NSException *ns) {
        }
    }               
}
```

Comment: Could you post some code so we know where you've got to? You will want to read about reference counting and memory allocation. Sounds like the controls have been de-allocated because their retain count reached zero.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Objective-C! :) The start can be a bit rough, but once you get used to it, it's great..

It's hard to answer your question without code, cause variables can "turn null" for many reasons. However since you're a newbie, it probably has to do with properties, retaining, etc.

There are obviously many related posts on the subject. Here's one: [Objective-C 101 (retain vs assign) NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380338/objective-c-101-retain-vs-assign-nsstring)

Basically in your .h file you need:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Car:NSObject{
    NSString *name;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
```

And then in your .m file in viewDidLoad:

```
self.name = [[[NSString alloc] init] autorelease];
// For strings, can use convinient function:
// self.name = [NSString string];
```

It's very important to use **self.name** and not just **name** as the former calls the property setter method and the latter does not (important for retaining the property correctly).

HTH, It's obviously general, but so is your question :)
Oded.