# Differences between weak and unsafe_unretained

Tags: objective-c, ios5, memory-management, ios4

So I had a project that supported iOS 4, so all my IBOutlets were `__unsafe_unretained` even IBOutlets that were in the nib but outside the controllers main view (Separate View in the same nib) and all worked great.

So the time has come and now the client wants to support only iOS 5 so our team changed all the `__unsafe_unretained`  IBOutlets for `__weak IBOutlets` but now the IBOutlets that are not inside the main view are set to `nil` (except in `viewdidload`) so we are unable to add them later.

If I think about it, it makes sense because if no view (main view) is retaining those IBOutlets they should be deallocated and zeroed (I don't know if that is the correct word), so the solution is to remove the `__weak` from those IBOutlets

But what doesn't make sense to me is Why the different behavior between `unsafe_unretained` and `weak`, in my head the `unsafe_unretained` ones should be deallocated and when the app tries to access them, they should point to an invalid reference and then the app should crash.

I thought that unsafe__unretained was the same as weak but without the zeroing.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks.

Comment: You are correct. unsafe_unretained does not nil the reference.

Answer (score 5):

> I thought that unsafe__unretained was the same as weak but without the zeroing.

It is, yes.

When Cocoa loads the nib, it creates all the objects autoreleased, so they are still there when `viewDidLoad` is invoked.  However, the autorelease pool has a lifetime that ends when control returns to the run loop.  At this point all the objects that aren't owned by anything will go away so any weak outlets will be zeroed at that point.

For most outlets, this is not a problem because objects in the NIB are already generally owned by something anyway.  So, for instance, a button in a view is owned by its parent view.  Having strong outlets that point to that button are therefore overkill or worse might result in a retain cycle.

Top level objects obviously don't have a parent view to own them so they need to be owned by something else e.g. a controller or "File's Owner".  If you are finding stuff disappears, you need to create a strong IBOutlet for it in File's owner.

For more detail, see [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW6).

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, and I'm completely aware of that, but my question is why when I use unsafe_unretained those IBOutlets never get deallocated and I can use them whenever(in time) I want?

Comment: @Ecarrion, in my opinion, it is there till the time that memory chunk not overridden/overwritten. And when it will be overwritten app gets a bad access.

Answer (score 1):

For future searchers who come across this question, I think CRD's [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13484472/2067021) to a similar question may explain. Even though the object has been deallocated, the memory that's referenced by the unsafe unretained pointer (which contains the actual object data) is not necessarily zeroed, so things may appear to behave properly until that memory is actually reused/modified/zeroed.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the app will crash when trying to access deallocated objects through your stale __unsafe_unretained references.

The reason it doesn't is very likely because the objects are being referenced by some other part of your app with strong references.

Try running with zombies enabled, that should cause an immediate crash when dereferencing the presumedly stale pointers.