# ARC and __unsafe_unretained

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I think I have a pretty good understanding of ARC and the proper use cases for selecting an appropriate lifetime qualifiers (`__strong`, `__weak`, `__unsafe_unretained`, and `__autoreleasing`).  However, in my testing, I've found one example that doesn't make sense to me.

As I understand it, both `__weak` and `__unsafe_unretained` do not add a retain count.  Therefore, if there are no other `__strong` pointers to the object, it is instantly deallocated (with immutable strings being an exception to this rule).  The only difference in this process is that `__weak` pointers are set to nil, and `__unsafe_unretained` pointers are left alone.

If I create a `__weak` pointer to a simple, custom object (composed of one NSString property), I see the expected (null) value when trying to access a property:

```
Test * __weak myTest = [[Test alloc] init];
myTest.myVal = @"Hi!";
NSLog(@"Value: %@", myTest.myVal); // Prints Value: (null)
```

Similarly, I would expect the `__unsafe_unretained` lifetime qualifier to cause a crash, due to the resulting dangling pointer.  However, it doesn't.  In this next test, I see the actual value:

```
Test * __unsafe_unretained myTest = [[Test alloc] init];
myTest.myVal = @"Hi!";
NSLog(@"Value: %@", myTest.myVal); // Prints Value: Hi!
```

Why doesn't the `__unsafe_unretained` object become deallocated?

**[EDIT]**: The object is being deallocated... if I try to substitute lines 2 - 3 with `NSLog(@"%@", myTest);` the app crashes (and an overridden `dealloc` in `Test` is being called immediately after the first line).  I know that immutable strings will continue to be available even with `__unsafe_unretained`, and that a direct pointer to the NSString would work.  I am just surprised that I could set a property on a deallocated object (line 2), and that it could later be dereferenced from a pointer to the deallocated object it belonged to (line 3)!  If anyone could explain that, it would definitely answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am just surprised that I could set a property on a deallocated object (line 2), and that it could later be dereferenced from a pointer to the deallocated object it belonged to (line 3)! If anyone could explain that, it would definitely answer my question.

When the object is deallocated it is not zeroed. As you have a pointer to the deallocated object and the property value is stored at some offset to that pointer it is *possible* that storing and retrieving that property value will succeed after deallocation, it is also quite possible that everything will blow up for some reason or other.

That your code works is quite fragile, try debugging it with "Show Disassembly While Debugging" and stepping through, you'll probably hit an access violation, or take down Xcode itself...

You should never be surprised that strange things happen in C, Objective-C, C++ or any of the family; instead reserve your surprise for so few strange things happening!

Answer (score 2):

Because the constant string in objc is a constant pointer to a heap address and the address is still valid.

**edited after comment:**

Maybe because the memory at the test objects address hasn't been overwritten and still contains that object? Speculating....

Comment: That makes sense for a pointer to an NSString, but it doesn't explain why `myTest` wouldn't be nil.  Strictly speaking, I would expect the second line, `myTest.myVal = @"Hi!"` would silently fail, because `myTest` **should** be instantly deallocated... and if `myTest` was deallocated, I would expect `myVal` would never be reached.

Comment: Woops. Right! Somehow overlooked that. Hmmm... Why doesn't it get deallocated?

Comment: .. rather in the first sentence, I meant: "it doesn't explain why `myTest` wouldn't be pointing to an empty block of memory" (not nil...).  I'm guessing you're on the right track though.  It might have something to do with how immutable strings are dereferenced. Perhaps that process still has the original NSString's address?

Answer (score 1):

You can see when `Test` is deallocated by implementing its `-dealloc` method and adding some simple logging.

However, even if Test is deallocated immediately, the memory it occupied in RAM may remain unchanged at the time you call `myVal`.

Comment: Also, I think under ARC you cant implement dealloc - or am I wrong here?

Comment: It's definitely deallocated.  When I run another test, and simply try to call `NSLog(@"%@", myTest);` that does crash.  So somehow because the value of the property is an immutable String, it's still able to deference it (even after the owning object is deallocated).

Comment: You can implement dealloc.  You just can't call it directly or call `[super dealloc]`

Answer (score 1):

`@"hi!"` produces a static global constant string instance that is, effectively, a singleton.   Thus, it'll never be deallocated because it wasn't really allocated in the first place (at least, it really isn't a normal heap allocation).

Anytime you want to explore object lifespan issues, always use a subclass of NSObject both to guarantee behavior and to make it easy to drop in logging hooks by overriding behavior.

Comment: Right... but @"hi!" isn't even being set until the object is deallocated... how is it able to set a property for a deallocated object? See my edited comments in my original question...

Comment: Also `Test` is a subclass of `NSObject`

Comment: As I understand, the immortality of NSStrings should be treated as an implementation detail and you should hold strong references to them regardless. I believe that immutable strings that are not compile-time constants are not immortal.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing strange there…
You need to have at least 1 strong reference to object to keep it alive.

```
Test * anTest = [[Test alloc] init];
Test * __weak myTest = anTest;
myTest.myVal = @"Hi!";
NSLog(@"Value: %@", myTest.myVal); // Prints Value: (Hi)
```

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. I was asking how my tests were showing that an object was kept alive, even though it DIDN'T have a strong reference.

Comment: weak: object killed and the pointer zeroed immediately, unsafe_unretained: object killed when pointer becomes 'out of scope'. So, _unsafe_unretained has no any useful effect for local pointers

Comment: I don't think your definition of unsafe_unretained is correct.  The only difference between that and weak is that the unsafe_unretained pointer is not zeroed out.  I don't believe it keeps the object alive till the pointer falls out of scope.  Re-read the comment I had written in the *EDIT* section of the question... the unsafe_unretained object is being deallocated immediately with ARC.