# non ARC and weak property- ios 5

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am using cocos2d v1.1.0-beta2b.
My project is NOT using ARC.
It used to work great but we have just tried changing now the minimal ios version for the project from 4.3 to 5.0 and we started to get compile time errors

"synthesize of weak properties is only allowed in ARC or GC mode"

it seems to be because of this(an example from cocos2d code)

```
// The delegate of the scroll layer object.
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= __IPHONE_5_0
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<CCScrollLayerDelegate> delegate;
#else
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<CCScrollLayerDelegate> delegate;
#endif
```

What should i do to solve it?

Is it safe to simply remove this if from the code and leave just the line
@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate; ?
(I am assuming it's ok as until today our code has used this anyway because until today we have targeted 4.3 and not 5)

Answer (score 2):

__weak is an arc only feature and there is no official replacement

Try MAZeroingWeakRef by mike ash
(https://github.com/mikeash/MAZeroingWeakRef)

OR

PLWeakCompatibility by plausible labs
(https://github.com/plausiblelabs/PLWeakCompatibility)

--

You CAN fall back on assign and code will compile but as there is no automatic nilling of assign variables (as opposed To __weak vars) it changes semantics and may cause crashes down the road

Comment: Until today the code that was used was with the assign(because this if false). Will the program behave the same way if i simply change the if to check if larger than ios 6? (Before the change to min. Ios 5 our program was pretty rock solid)

Comment: Assign is no weak. weak is no assign. Id deem it very likely that it will remain good though

Answer (score 0):

Use `unsafe_unretained` instead of `weak` in your property declaration, and it should mostly work the same way.

`unsafe_unretained` is supported in both iOS 4.x and 5.0 and above, so it gives you backwards compatibility

Comment: It aint that  :) see more

  [1]: http://It%20aint%20that%20%20:%29%20see%20more%20http://stackoverflow.com/a/11123303/1704346