# iOS, creating a business object in a loop, adding it to array

Tags: ios

I am a .NET and java programmer doing iOS, thought I should mention that ( maybe I am biased to business objects, classes)...
anyway.

I have some objects streaming in as JSON, I want to have them all inputted into an array, I created a simple class to represent this object and initialize its properties .

BizObject.h

```
   @interface BizObject : NSObject
   @property (readwrite, copy) NSString* back;
   @property (readwrite, copy) NSString* front;
   @end
```

BizObject.m

```
 #import "BizObject.h"
 @implementation BizObject
 @synthesize front, back;
 //No init method, don't know if I need one !!
 @end
```

Now when I get the JSON entry, I do this

```
  NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSJSONSerialization
  JSONObjectWithData:JSONData
  options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
  error:&error];
  if (!tempArray) {
     NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", error);
  } else {

  for(NSDictionary *tempBizObject in tempArray) {
  BizObject * newBizObject = [[BizObject alloc] init];
     [newBizObject setBack: [tempBizObject valueForKey:@"back"]];
     [newBizObject setFront:[tempBizObject valueForKey:@"front"]];
     [bizObjectsArray addObject:newBizObject];
  }
}
for(BizObject *bizObject in bizObjectsArray) {
   NSLog(@"back: %@", bizObject.back);
   NSLog(@"fron: %@", bizObject.front);
}
```

I have some questions here :

1 : anything wrong with this kind of setup?

2 : I am getting this error

```
  malloc: *** error for object 0x165060: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

3 : Is this an overkill for just creating an array of object, all of its properties are just strings??

Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
@interface BizObject : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* back;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* front;
@end
```

[Read this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7085234/1704346)

Answer (score 0):

you are releasing the un allocated object . that means somewhere in code you are releasing already released object or releasing not created object , check for that. your above code not contained that snippet

Comment: But I do not release any objects? this is all ARC.

Answer (score 0):

The are no problem with the code shown, the crash is an other object. Enable Zombie Object to see more détails of the crash.