# When should i use assign in Objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I understand the reason i should use *retain*, but why should I ever use assign? (*besides to avoid retain cycles*)

**[EDIT]**
So if i understand Chuck's answer on [https://stackoverflow.com/questions...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380338/objective-c-101-retain-vs-assign-nsstring) correctly, when ever I use assign, the variable would lose scope once it gets out of scope of the method just like it does in regular C-type language behavior?

Comment: There's a similar question with a good answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380338/objective-c-101-retain-vs-assign-nsstring

Comment: @RaysonK too bad none of the answers were ever accepted.

Comment: added an edit to my original question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should assign things that aren't objects. Any C type (such as int, float, char, double, struct, and enum) should be assigned.

Comment: Isn't assign a default?

Comment: Then why is UIWebViewDelegate assign 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/delegate

Answer (score 2):

Few examples I can think of:

1. It is not an object. Such as BOOL, int
2. Most of the times delegate properties are assigned (to prevent cycles)

Comment: delegates are weak

Answer (score 1):

1. Anything that is not an object
2. Delegates
3. IBOutlets that are not top level (i.e. subviews since those are already retained by the view)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that Chuck's answer from the linked question is correct, there's not really a "scope" in Objective-C. Sounds like you should just use `assign` for any primitives, like ints or BOOLs. Anything that you need to have ownership of, use `retain` (or other commands, as Chuck describes).

Comment: Ok. I understand that i need assign for primitives. Now what if i use assign for an object. Are you saying that that object is not guaranteed to be valid though-out its use if it wasn't previously retained?

Comment: I can't say for sure because this is inferring from what that other user said, but near as I can tell, you're leaving it to the program to decide when the variable in question is done being used. Somebody correct me if I'm wrong, but I think `assign` just means you're going to change the value of the variable.