# Property attributes in custom setters/getter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa

If I create property, for example:

```
@property NSString *selectedSubProductId;
```

and create setter and getter:

```
- (NSString *)selectedSubProductId {}

- (void)setSelectedSubProductId:(NSString *)value_ {}
```

XCode says that `"Deault property attribute 'assign' not appropriate for non-gc object"`. Do attributes have any meaning in this case? Does it matter if i make them `copy` or `assign` or are they only cue for `@synthesize` to create desired methods? If so, how should I disable the warnings?

Comment: What's the version of your Xcode? I'm not seeing any such warnings when I copy-paste your code into my environment (I have Xcode 4.4.1).

Answer (score 1):

If it is object, you should use retain/copy property modifier.

For example:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *selectedSubProductId;
```

If the modifiers are missing, `assign` modifier is enabled by default. But it is only valid for scalar (`int`, `float`...) or `struct`.

You may get more details in [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

That warning says that you are using a default property atribute (assign) because you forgot to say how do you want to hold your object.

If you want to "remove" the warning use a retain/copy property:
    `@property (copy) NSString *selectedSubProductId;`

However, in Strings you should use copy. For more information please [visit this question on stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380338/objective-c-101-retain-vs-assign-nsstring)