# Ascess the instance variable globally in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, extern

I am new to iphone development.I want to access a variable declared in one view in another view.How can i achieve it.Whether it is possible by using extern variable, if so how to declare and implement it.Can i achieve it by using delegates?then so how to implement it.Please guide me.I am  browsing google to get and idea to achieve it, i came up with delegates and extern variable, but i dont know how implement or use these methods(delegates,extern variable).Please tell me the right way to achieve it.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could declare and implement a property on first view and set it from the second view.

This requires that the second view has a reference to the first view.

For example:

**FirstView.h**

```
@interface FirstView : UIView {
    NSString *data;
}
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *data;
@end
```

**FirstView.m**

```
@implementation FirstView
// implement standard retain getter/setter for data:
@synthesize data;
@end
```

**SecondView.m**

```
@implementation SecondView
- (void)someMethod {
    // if "myFirstView" is a reference to a FirstView object, then
    // access its "data" object like this:
    NSString *firstViewData = myFirstView.data;
}
@end
```

Comment: @ implementation SecondView should i import firstView.h

Comment: What is myFirstView.name,"name" refers to what?

Comment: Yes, you need to import FirstView.h in SecondView.h or SecondView.m. Sorry, "name" should have been "data", it has been fixed.

Comment: Hi, it's better to use copy instead of retain for NSString properties (this question explains why better than I ever could : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387959/nsstring-property-copy-or-retain)

Comment: Thanks. I figured someone would mention that. I don't typically use mutable strings.