# the way to transfer NSString variables among multi viewcontrollers

Tags: iphone

As I know, I can use global variable transfer the value among the multi viewcontrollers of a project.

But I hope to know the best way to transfer NSString variables between multi viewcontrollers and the way to avoid memory leak.

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to pass parameters between your view controllers is to use properties. If applicable, have your app delegate set the initial value in your root view controller. Then you set the property before you push a new view controller on your navigation stack, or raise a new view controller modally. e.g.:

```
MyViewController* myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:nil];
myViewController. someStringVariable = someStringVariable;
[self.navigationController pushViewController: myViewController animated:YES];
[myViewController release];
```

When passing `NSString` objects, you will normally want to use `copy` instead of `retain` when declaring the property. (See [this previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387959/nsstring-property-copy-or-retain) for more detail.) e.g.:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSString* someStringVariable;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* someStringVariable;

@end
```

Avoid leaking memory by releasing the property in the view controller's `dealloc` method, e.g.:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [someStringVariable release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```