# object-C class property should add "self" while assign its value?

Tags: objective-c, reference, self

I am new here, and already searched related articles like "Is “self” necessary?" and "Setting an Objective-C class property without using a self reference" However i still can't get a clear answer which can explain my case.

I have a simple class and my UI has two textfield and one button, here is the code:

```
@interface testViewController : UIViewController {
    NSString       *teststring_A;
    NSString       *teststring_B;
    IBOutlet UITextField *textfield_1;
    IBOutlet UITextField *textfield_2;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *teststring_A;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *teststring_B;
- (IBAction)action1:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)action2:(id)sender;
@end

@implementation testViewController
@synthesize teststring_A;
@synthesize teststring_B;

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}
- (IBAction)action1:sender
{
    teststring_A = textfield_1.text ;
    NSLog(@"teststring_A in action 1 is : %@\n", teststring_A);

    teststring_B = textfield_2.text ;
    NSLog(@"teststring_B in action 1 is : %@\n", teststring_B);
}
- (IBAction)action2:(id)sender
{
 NSLog(@"teststring_A in action 2 is : %@\n", teststring_A);
 NSLog(@"teststring_B in action 2 is : %@\n", teststring_B);
}
```

the output is :

```
2010-11-19 15:32:14.827 test[419:207] teststring_A in action 1 is : 123
2010-11-19 15:32:14.829 test[419:207] teststring_B in action 1 is : 456
2010-11-19 15:32:14.927 test[419:207] teststring_A in action 2 is : 123
2010-11-19 15:32:14.929 test[419:207] teststring_B in action 2 is : {(
    >
)}
```

And when click button, it triggers action1 first then action2. My problem is... in action2, the value of teststring_B becomes incorrect, sometimes the application even crashes. What confuses me is (1) why is the value of teststring_A correct???  (2) teststring_B is assigned by textfield_2.text which is not created with 'alloc', so suppose the pointer should exist all the time. then why teststring_B's value becomes incorrect in action2 ??? (3) in dealloc, I should release teststring_A and teststring_B, right? (i think so )

All I know is if I add 'self.', like 'self.teststring_B = textfield_2.text;' then there won't be problem. the value will be correct. So I would like to know the technical reason.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing *variables* and *properties*. Properties are backed by variables, but in reality they are methods.

Here, you define a property named `teststring_B` which retains anything that gets assigned to it (and releases the old value). The equivalent methods would look like this (simplified):

```
- (NSString *)teststring_B {
    // Return the content of the variable teststring_B.
    return teststring_B;
}

- (void)setTeststring_B:(NSString *)val {
    // Retain new value.
    [val retain];
    // Release old value in variable teststring_B
    [teststring_B release];
    // Assign the new, retained value to variable teststring_B
    teststring_B = val;
}
```

You can now use the property in two ways: either with `[self setTeststring_B:foo];` or with `self.teststring_B = foo;`. The important point is that the later is just a convenient way of writing, the compiler will translate it into the first form, that is the compiler will turn the `self.foo = bar;` lines into `[self setFoo:bar];`.

Now that we have this explained, on to your crash: you've got a string value which is most likely autoreleased. Now you just plain assign it to the *variable* `teststring_B`, not the property. And you forgot to retain the value. The property would have retained that value for you.

Now the assigned value was autoreleased (it didn't know you've got a variable still pointing to it) and later a new object came to life at the exact same memory location (if you're lucky). In any case, the `teststring_B` variable is now not pointing to the text as you thought it would, but to some random object (or to garbage).

There are two ways to fix this:

```
// First retain, then release; it might be the same object
// and if you would release it first its retain count might
// drop to 0 and get cleaned up before you can retain it again.
NSString *tmp = [textfield_2.text retain];
[teststring_B release];
teststring_B = tmp;

// Better !
self.teststring_B = textfield_2.text;
```

Comment: Hi DarkDust, thx for so much detail. So can i make this conclusion?
(1) in my incorrect code, teststring_B is treated as a local variable, not property of my class. that is why in action2 function, teststring_B is considered as a new local variable. is my understanding correct?
(2) in any method of the class, if i want to access the property, read/write, i must add 'self.' , right?

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the variable directly without using the self will not retain it. So when you accessing it later the variable got auto-released and makes your application crash.

so you can write

```
1) [self setTeststring_B:textfield_2.text]; or
2) the dot syntax self.teststring_B = textfield_2.text; or
3) teststring_b = [textfield_2.text retain]
```

Comment: I'm just illustrating the case where the the variable is deallocated. retain vs copy IMHO should be another topic.

Comment: THX, Shaggy Frog and Nevin. I am more clear. So can I say this... in my incorrect code, teststring_B is treated as a local variable, not property of my class. that is why in action2 function, teststring_B is considered as a new local variable. is my understanding correct?

Comment: It's all about memory management. any object obtained without calling alloc, new or copy* should be considered auto-released, therefore you cannot assume it's still there when you access it again in a later stage.

Comment: ah... this is the key point. now i have no confusing for this part. thx.

Comment: You're welcome. Check out the apple doc regarding this: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing now is simple assignment. That can cause a crash if the object `teststring_A` or `teststring_B` point to is deallocated; this is also called a dangling reference.

The reason only simple assignment is happening is because you aren't accessing the setters through the `@property` semantics; you could get a `retain` on those `NSString` objects by doing `self.teststring_A = textfield_1.text` instead.

**However, you should be using `copy` with `NSString` properties.** See: [NSString property: copy or retain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387959/nsstring-property-copy-or-retain)

In other words, you want this:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *teststring_A;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *teststring_B;
```

and this:

```
self.teststring_A = textfield_1.text ;
self.teststring_B = textfield_1.text ;
```

Comment: thank you. Shaggy Frog, I will look into copy/retain issue more. thx.