# Unknown Memory Leak in iPhone

Tags: iphone, string, memory-leaks, autorelease

I am currently building an app for the iPhone and cannot figure out why I keep getting a memory leak to appear in the Leaks Instrument tool.

Here is the code and I have added comments to two places of where it is happening.

```
NSString *pathname = [[NSBundle mainBundle]  pathForResource:self.toUseFile ofType:@"txt" inDirectory:@"/"];
    //Line below causes a leak
    self.rawCrayons = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pathname encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

    self.sectionArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) [self.sectionArray addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];


    for(int i=0; i<self.rawCrayons.count; i++)
    {
        self.string = [self.rawCrayons objectAtIndex:i];
        NSUInteger firstLetter = [ALPHA rangeOfString:[string substringToIndex:1]].location;
        if (firstLetter != NSNotFound)
        {
            NSInteger audio = AUDIONUM(self.string);
            NSInteger pictures = PICTURESNUM(self.string);
            NSInteger videos = VIDEOSNUM(self.string);
            //Line below causes a leak
            [[self.sectionArray objectAtIndex:firstLetter] addObject:[[Term alloc] initToCall:NAME(self.string):audio:pictures:videos]];
        }

        [self.string release];
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

Here are my property declarations.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *filteredArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *sectionArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UISearchBar *searchBar;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UISearchDisplayController *searchDC;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *toUseFile;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *rawCrayons;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *string;

@property (nonatomic, retain) TermViewController *childController;
```

Here are the leaks that are occurring after follow Nick Weaver's fixes.
[image: Memory Leaks]

Here is an expanded version of one of the NSCFString. [image: Memory Leaks in Depth]

And another image.  [image: Another one in depth]

Image with the Responsible Caller:  [image: Responsible Caller]

Also, because this may be useful, here are the properties for Term:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger numberAudio;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger numberPictures;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger numberVideos;
```

And the implementation:

```
@implementation Term

@synthesize name, numberAudio, numberPictures, numberVideos;

- (Term*)initToCall:(NSString*) toSetName:(NSInteger) audio:(NSInteger) pictures:(NSInteger) videos
{
    self.name = [toSetName retain];
    self.numberAudio = audio;
    self.numberPictures = pictures;
    self.numberVideos = videos;

    return self;
}

- (NSString*)getName
{
    return [[name retain] autorelease];
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    [name release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: It might be helpful to know how the `rawCrayons` property is defined.

Comment: @Jim Blackler It's in the code I posted, isn't it?

Comment: I mean the definition from the header file, e.g. `@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSButton *myButton;`

Comment: @Jim Blackler I have added my property declarations above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, try this changed Version of Temp. I've deleted the getter because you have already one by synthesizing. You cann use the getter like this for name:

```
term.name
```

The problem was how you set the name: you want a copy of the name and setting it with the synthesized setter without calling a retain should do the trick. You could, of course, have set it with the retained property of name but you should have left out retain, like this `self.name =  toSetName;`. The setter will retain it for you.

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger numberAudio;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger numberPictures;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger numberVideos;


@implementation Term

@synthesize name, numberAudio, numberPictures, numberVideos;

- (Term*)initToCall:(NSString*) toSetName:(NSInteger) audio:(NSInteger) pictures:(NSInteger) videos
{
    self.name = toSetName;
    self.numberAudio = audio;
    self.numberPictures = pictures;
    self.numberVideos = videos;

    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    [name release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

---

Adding an object to an array will retain the instance, so the retain is 2 because you call

[[Term alloc] initToCall..

Do something like

```
Term *term = [[Term alloc] initToCall..];

[theArray addObject:term];

[term release];
```

**1. See the arrow in the first line in the address column? Click it!**
[image]

**2. After clicking :)**
[image]

Comment: @Nick Weaver I followed this and am now getting a leak at NSCFString which when I double click it, it's all just Assembly Code.

Comment: please show us the declaration of your properties in your header file.

Comment: @Nick Weaver I have added my property declarations above.

Comment: First of all, change your NSString properties from retain to copy: NSStrings are immutable so you want a copy of it not something that can change in the background by some process.

Comment: @Nick Weaver Should that be done throughout the entire app for all NSStrings?

Comment: My opinion is: yes, I do it that way. If you don't store whole books in the strings, copy is the right choice for NSStrings. Have a look at [NSString property copy or retain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387959/nsstring-property-copy-or-retain), this is explaining the difference very well.

Comment: Ok thanks.  And this should fix the memory leak at NSCFString?

Comment: I can't tell, you have to find out. The problem solving here is iterative, I don't have the running code, so I can only help with the next step depending on the given information.

Comment: @Nick Weaver I am not getting less leaks and I have posted an image in my original post of the two leaks that I am getting.

Comment: @Flipper can you expand one of the two items and dive into one line by doubleclicking it? Then post a screenshot, please. The last column should be titled Responsible Caller.

Comment: @Nick Weaver I have added two images because I could not find where Responsible Caller was.

Comment: Look at the two screenshots I added to my answer. The last one you get by clicking the arrow, or double click.

Comment: I have added the other screenshot as well as some more code that seems like it may be relevant (after looking at my screenshot).

Comment: Thanks for the new code, I think we are close to a solution. Look at my answer update.

Comment: I have tried over and over to get a memory leak and have been unsuccessful in my attempts therefore making your answer right and have fixed all of my problems.  Thank you SO SO SO much! =)

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell you why the first one is leaking, because we don't know what the property is declared as. Is it retain? copy? assign? what?

The last one is fairly self explanatory though, you're taking ownership of a Term object, and not releasing it when it's added. addObject: retains its argument, meaning if you don't need that Term anymore, you need to give up ownership. I.e., pass `-autorelease` to the result of your `initToCall::::` (which btw is a very bad name for a method)

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
[[self.sectionArray objectAtIndex:firstLetter] addObject:[[Term alloc] initToCall:NAME(self.string):audio:pictures:videos]];
```

to:

```
Term *tempTerm = [[Term alloc] initToCall:NAME(self.string):audio:pictures:videos];
[[self.sectionArray objectAtIndex:firstLetter] addObject:tempTerm];
[tempTerm release];
```

By alloc'ing an object you are responsible for it's release.