# @property retain OR copy

Tags: objective-c, copy, properties, nsmutabledictionary, retain

First I read this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387959/nsstring-property-copy-or-retain)

I think I should use "copy" in my programe.
Problem is using NSMutableDictionary copy it will terminate.

***** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary removeAllObjects]: mutating method sent to immutable object'**

I have no idea about "mutating method sent to immutable object".
I didn't set NSDictionary to NSMutabledictionary pointer.

Here is my code

.h file

```
@interface Button : NSObject {

@private
    NSString*               gID;                                 
    NSString*               gBackColor;                          
    NSString*               gIconImage;                          
    int                     gIndex;                              
    BOOL                    gEnable;                            
    BOOL                    gVisible;
    NSString*               gText;
    
    NSMutableDictionary*    gEvents;
    
    
    BOOL                    gUseCircle;                 
}

@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString                 *ID;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString                 *BackColor;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString                 *IconImage;
@property int Index;
@property BOOL Enable;
@property BOOL Visible;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString                 *Text;
@property (nonatomic,getter=getEvents,retain) NSMutableDictionary       *Events;
@property BOOL UseCircle;

@end
```

.m file

```
@implementation Button
@synthesize ID = gID;
@synthesize BackColor = gBackColor;
@synthesize IconImage = gIconImage;
@synthesize Index = gIndex;
@synthesize Enable = gEnable;
@synthesize Visible = gVisible;
@synthesize Text = gText;
@synthesize Events = gEvents;
@synthesize UseCircle = gUseCircle;

-(NSMutableDictionary*) getEvents
{
    if (!gEvents) 
    {
        gEvents = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:20];
    }
    return gEvents;
}

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) 
    {
        gID = @"";
        gBackColor = @"";
        gIconImage = @"";
        gIndex = 0;
        gText = @"";
        
        gUseCircle = NO;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    [gID release];
    [gBackColor release];
    [gIconImage release];
    [gText release];
    
    [gEvents removeAllObjects];
    [gEvents release];
    gEvents = nil;
    
    [super dealloc];
}
```

And implement

```
tBtnXML.Events = [self SplitEvents:tNode];
```

SplitEvents function:

```
-(NSMutableDictionary*) SplitEvents:(NSDictionary*)pEvents
{
    NSMutableDictionary *tEvents = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:5];
    // code blabla
    //.
    //.
    //.
    [tEvents setObject:tEvent forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:tEventName]];
    [tEvent release];
            
            

            return [tEvents autorelease];
}
```

But I chage  NSMutableDictionary* gEvents property from copy to retain , it execute normal.

Colud anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

If my code is incorrect with dealloc,please tell me.

Thank you appriciate.

Yes, So I fixed my setter:

```
-(void) setEvents:(NSMutableDictionary*) pEvents
{
    NSMutableDictionary* tNewDict = [pEvents mutableCopy];
    [gEvents removeAllObjects];
    [gEvents release];
    gEvents = tNewDict;
}
```

This work with no error.

It helps me a lot.

But I can't vote up >"<~

So thank you Bavarious :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, mutable properties should be `retain` instead of `copy`. When you declare a property as being `copy`, the synthesised setter method sends `-copy` to the object that’s being assigned to the property. In the case of mutable objects (e.g. `NSMutableDictionary`), sending `-copy` to them makes *an immutable copy*, effectively creating an object of immutable type (e.g. `NSDictionary`) instead.

So in:

```
tBtnXML.Events = [self SplitEvents:tNode];
```

the synthesised setter sends `-copy` to `[self SplitEvents:tNode]`, thus creating an immutable copy of that dictionary (i.e., an `NSDictionary` instance), and assign it to `gEvents`. This is the cause of your error: `gEvents` is declared as `NSMutableDictionary` but points to an `NSDictionary` instead.

For the record, mutable classes usually declare a `-mutableCopy` method that does make a mutable copy. It is not used by declared properties, though. If you do not want to use `retain`, you need to implement a custom setter that uses `-mutableCopy`.

Comment: @wei `NSMutableDictionary` does implement `-mutableCopy` — in fact, it conforms to the `NSMutableCopying` protocol. The problem is that, when synthesising Objective-C declared properties, setter methods **do not** use `-mutableCopy`.

Comment: Thank you for reply :)
Is it strange `NSMutableDictionary` copy return an immutable object ?
I thik I understand my error.

Comment: Ok~~~ I got it~ >"<~~~~ The problem is that, when synthesising Objective-C declared properties, setter methods do not use -mutableCopy