# Objective-C copy and retain

Tags: objective-c, copy, retain

When should I use copy instead of using retain? I didn't quite get it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSString property: copy or retain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387959/nsstring-property-copy-or-retain) or [Objective C Assign Copy Retain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510913/) or [Retain Copy of autoreleased objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416963/) or [When to use retain and when to use copy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087208/) or [@property: Retain or copy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616170/) or [many others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bobjc%5D+copy+retain)

Comment: In this questions defense, the others are all specific to property types, but yes, this question has been asked a lot.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You would use `copy` when you want to guarantee the state of the object.

```
NSMutableString *mutString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"ABC"];
NSString *b = [mutString retain];
[mutString appendString:@"Test"];
```

At this point b was just messed up by the 3rd line there.

```
NSMutableString *mutString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"ABC"];
NSString *b = [mutString copy];
[mutString appendString:@"Test"];
```

In this case b is the original string, and isn't modified by the 3rd line.

This applies for all mutable types.

Comment: It's worth noting that many immutable types will implement -copy by calling -retain; Since their value will never change, there's no point in having two copies in memory.  That said, absent futher info, you should always code as if you don't know whether a particular object is mutable or not. Just because you type your property as NSString doesn't mean someone won't pass an NSMutableString to it (as illustrated above.)

Answer (score 7):

**retain** : It is done on the created object, and it just increase the reference count.

**copy** -- It creates a new object and when new object is created retain count will be 1.
Hope this may help you.

Comment: copy does not always create a new object

Comment: so in retain we increase the reference count onto the same object, while for copy we increase the reference count on a new object?

Answer (score 4):

Copy is useful when you do not want the value that you receive to get changed without you knowing. For example if you have a property that is an `NSString` and you rely on that string not changing once it is set then you need to use copy. Otherwise someone can pass you an `NSMutableString` and change the value which will in turn change the underlying value of your `NSString`. The same thing goes with an `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` except copy on an array just copies all the pointer references to a new array but will prevent entries from being removed and added.