# Warning in garbage collected Cocoa-app about properties

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, properties, garbage-collection

This is my code:

```
@interface Object : NSObject {
@private
  NSArray *array;
}

@property NSArray *array;

@end
```

And the `@synthesize` in the implementation. I get a compiler warning in the line with the `@property`:

> warning: default assign attribute on property 'array' which implements NSCopying protocol is not appropriate with -fobjc-gc[-only]

If I write the property as `@property (assign) NSArray *array` it does not show up. What is this about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you are creating a property that is a pointer to an object. Assign, which is the default, is not appropriate for objects, which should be declared as `retain` or `copy`.

In your case you should define your property as:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *array;
```

You could use `retain` instead of `copy` here, but there are [good reasons to use `copy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387959/nsstring-property-copy-or-retain).

**edit**

To answer the deeper question you seem to be asking - have a [look at this thread](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/218597-appropriateness-of-assign-attribute-and-fobj-gc-only.html) from the Cocoa mailing lists.

Are you using the LLVM compiler or gcc?

Comment: Okay, so this depends on the mutability of `array`? How is this affected by the garbage collection, as stated in the warning?

Comment: As jer said - if you're being explicit about it, it lets you do it.

Comment: I understand that, but _why_ does it warn me about that only if I'm using garbage collection? I just want to understand why someone put this warning there ;)

Comment: LLVM. I understand it now. The issue is that `assign` in a GC environment produces a strong reference, whereas it is weak in a non-GC app. Edited your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Properties default to assign. Your property is an assign.

Comment: Because you have to be explicit about it

Answer (score 0):

Regarding assign vs copy in GC enabled app, I found this via google...

http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/194064-use-of-assign-vs-copy-for-accessors-in-garbage-collected-app.html

I think we usually use assign, but will use copy if needed, like for example, for NSString object. So to get rid of warning, we just explicitly specify it as assign.