# Message sent to deallocated instance on object that should exist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

`[CFString isEqualToString:]: message sent to deallocated instance`

This is the error I'm getting. I have a View controller with a Property that is an NSMutableArray and it contains some Player objects.

Then I have a method that switches to another view, where I can add and remove players. When I load the next view I pass a pointer to the first view, to the second view. I then updated the Array by using `[previousView.playerList addObject:p];` where p is the newly created player object.

The error comes, however when I attempt to display the list of players in the second view's table view. when I try to access `[previousView.playerlist objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];` I get the error above.

here's the code:

This is in the first View, where it loads the second and passes itself to the property of the second.

```
- (IBAction) addPlayerButton:(id)sender {
    [self retain];
    PlayerListViewController *playerListViewController = [[PlayerListViewController alloc] init];
    playerListViewController.previousView = self;
    [UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:playerListViewController.view duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:nil];
}
```

This is where I initialize the player and add it to the array.

```
- (IBAction)addPlayer:(id)sender {
    Player *p = [[[Player alloc] initWithPlayerName:playerNameField.text withOrder:[previousView.playerList count] withDelegate:previousView] retain];
    [previousView.playerList addObject:p];
    [playerNameField resignFirstResponder];
    [playerTableView reloadData];
}
```

And here is where I get my error

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MyCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    Player* p = [previousView.playerList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [cell.textLabel setText:[p playerName]];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    return cell;
}
```

I'm getting the error on the line where I set the cell text. `[cell.textLabel setText:[p playerName]];`

Does anyone know where I'm screwing up? I will post more code if needed.

I trimmed Player.m to only include the Synthesis and Initalization, because the rest is A LOT of code, that doesnt really have to do with this error, because it isin't being called.

Player.h

```
@protocol playerProtocol <NSObject>

@optional
- (void) playerDied:(id)playerObject;
- (void) playerWasAdded:(id)playerObject;
- (void) playerLifeDidChange:(id)playerObject;
@end

@interface Player : NSObject {
    id <playerProtocol> delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *playerName;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) int playerLife;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) int playerPoison;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) int order;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) Boolean invincible;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <playerProtocol>delegate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *viewPane;
@property (nonatomic) Boolean shown;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) int minusButton;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) int plusButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *readout;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *playerLifeNumerals;


- (id) initWithPlayerName:(NSString *)playersName withOrder:(int)Order withDelegate:(id)d;
- (void) setPlayerLife:(int)pplayerLife;
- (void) setPlayerPoison:(int)pplayerPoison;
- (NSArray *) getLifeNumeralsFromPlayer:(Player *)playerObject;

@end
```

Player.m

```
@implementation Player

@synthesize playerLife, playerName, playerPoison, order, delegate, invincible, viewPane, readout, shown, minusButton, plusButton, playerLifeNumerals;

#pragma mark - Custom Initalizer

- (id) initWithPlayerName:(NSString *)playersName withOrder:(int)Order withDelegate:(id)d {

    [super init];
    delegate = d;
    playerLife = 20;
    playerPoison = 0;
    order = Order;
    playerName = playersName;
    invincible = NO;
    [delegate playerWasAdded:self];
    viewPane = nil;
    readout = nil;
    shown = NO;
    return self;
}
```

Also here's the arrays declaration `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *playerList;`

Comment: You should probably post the declaration and implementation of `Player`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In:

```
- (id) initWithPlayerName:(NSString *)playersName withOrder:(int)Order withDelegate:(id)d {

    [super init];
    delegate = d;
    playerLife = 20;
    playerPoison = 0;
    order = Order;
    playerName = playersName;
    invincible = NO;
    [delegate playerWasAdded:self];
    viewPane = nil;
    readout = nil;
    shown = NO;
    return self;
}
```

you are not retaining `playerName`. Note that although you’ve declared your `playerName` property as `retain` (and it should be `copy` instead), you’re not using the property setter in `-initWith…`. Instead, you’re directly accessing the backing instance variable. Since you’re directly assigning `playersName` to the instance variable, you need to manually send it `-retain` (or, better yet, `-copy`).

Check whether you need this in your other declared properties. Also, you should follow the idiom:

```
self = [super init];
if (self) { … }
return self;
```

in your initialisers.

**Edit:** you need to carefully review your code with regard to memory management practices since you’re leaking in more than one place. For example, in:

```
- (IBAction) addPlayerButton:(id)sender {
    [self retain];
    PlayerListViewController *playerListViewController = [[PlayerListViewController alloc] init];
    playerListViewController.previousView = self;
    [UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:playerListViewController.view duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:nil];
}
```

what’s the purpose of `[self retain]`, and is there a balancing release?

Another example: in:

```
Player *p = [[[Player alloc] initWithPlayerName:playerNameField.text withOrder:[previousView.playerList count] withDelegate:previousView] retain];
[previousView.playerList addObject:p];
```

you get +1 ownership from `+alloc`, another `+1` from `-retain`, and the array also owns `p`, hence another +1. You should replace `-retain` with `-autorelease` to balance the number of times you’re taking ownership of that object.

Comment: Yea i was just trying to find the bug before i played with retains and releases on this code. it usually takes me a while to get it right.

Comment: Worked GREAT you are a GOD!!! i wish i could give you +100. that has been bugging me all weekend.

Comment: One more question regarding this code if you don't mind, do you know of a good tutorial that explains when i should use copy or retain? my iOS programming book really only explained retain.

Comment: @Kron There are a few questions on Stack Overflow about it, one of which is: [NSString property: copy or retain?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/387959/557219)