# How do I access a pointer in multiple instance methods?

Tags: objective-c, variables, instance

I do not understand how to declare an pointer that can be accessed in more than one method. The following code uses `myContainer` to store a number which is utilized when `useMyContainer` is called.

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
    NSString *myContainer;
    IBOutlet UILabel *display;
}
- (IBAction)storeToMyContainer: (UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)useMyContainer: (UIButton *)sender;
@end

@implementation MyViewController
- (IBAction)storeToMyContainer: (UIButton *)sender {
myContainer = sender.titleLabel.text;
}
- (IBAction)useMyContainer: (UIButton *)sender {
[someOtherClass doSomethingWith:[myContainer doubleValue]];
}
@end
```

What I don't understand is that when I use `display` in the same manner, I don't have a problem. What do I need to do to access `myContainer` in `useMyContainer` in this manner?

Some thoughts: I know this is a memory management issue, and I am almost sure that a `retain` is being called on display (probably by the .xib file?) and that is why `display` hangs around long enough to be used in both methods.

I know a work around that involves using a double and an int, but I consider this to be messy, and as I'm taking a class on this I wanna to know the baller way to handle this.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way of handling this would be to take care of memory management for your 'myContainer' field.

I would go with:

```
myContainer = [sender.titleLabel.text copy];
```

It is recommended to use copy for NSString. Relevant thread for that discussion is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387959/nsstring-property-copy-or-retain).

Also, please don't forget to release the memory for the 'myContainer' field. You can do that in your dealloc method:

```
-(void) dealloc {
    [myContainer release];
    [super dealloc];    
}
```

Comment: is it also possible to `[myContainer release]`; after I use it in `useMyContainer:`?

Comment: technically yes, that would work. You would basically let go of the value in the `myContainer` field right away. However, by doing that, you are putting a very implicit assumption into your code. The assumption is that: `storeToMyContainer:` should be invoked before `useMyContainer:` && `useMyContainer:` cannot be called consecutively. If `useMyContainer:` is called twice in a row (without calling `storeToMyContainer:`), then the second call would fail due to the released `myContainer` field.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in saying that this is a memory management issue. Basically, you're not "claiming ownership" of the string being stored in `myContainer`. Some (short) period of time after `storeToMyContainer:` is called, the autorelease pool containing the sender's string is drained and, because you didn't say that you're still using it, it ceases to exist.

To claim ownership of the string, you must `retain` (or `copy`) it. So, updating your code:

```
- (IBAction)storeToMyContainer:(UIButton *)sender {
    myContainer = [sender.titleLabel.text retain];
}
```

Another approach would be to use [properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html). Either way, I recommend you have a read over the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/index.html), specifically [Basic Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1).