# How to set NSString* property from another class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

Please look to the following code.

FirstViewController.h:

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {
    NSString* inputData;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy/retain) NSString* inputData;
```

FirstViewController.m:

```
@synthesize inputData;
```

SecondViewController.m:

```
- (IBAction)buttonSaveDown {
    [firstViewController setInputData:@"Text"];
    firstViewController.inputData = @"Text";
    firstViewController.inputData = [[NSString stringWithString:@"Text"] retain];
}
```

Add breakpoints after every line with inputData. Check firstViewController.inputData - it's '(null)'! Why?

```
Printing description of inputData:
(null)
```

Also I try 'Edit value' in the debugger. After setting value the result is '(null)' too.

There's no any warnings on the build. Please help anybody. Thanks a lot!

**To moderators:** Sorry, but someone deleted the same previous question when I asked to delete all comments on it.

Comment: Is FirstViewController initialized? Also on your 3rd attempt of setting inputData you do not need the retain call if your @property directive is set to copy or retain, this will actually cause a memory leak.

Comment: Are you sure that firstViewController is valid in the buttonSaveDown method?  If it's nil, then none of that will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `firstViewController` variable is not set to anything. You need to set it to a valid instance of FirstViewController before you can do anything useful with it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* inputData;
```

Then these each should work:

```
[firstViewController setInputData:@"Text"];
firstViewController.inputData = @"Text";
firstViewController.inputData = [NSString stringWithString:@"Text"];
```

Comment: Don't help. inputData: '(null)'. Sorry, but it's incorrect answer.

Comment: regardless, 'copy/retain' is an invalid syntax, as far as I know. Pick one of the two. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387959/nsstring-property-copy-or-retain for suggestions on which.