# Difference between methods of assigning property in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

Here are 2 methods to assign property in Objective-C :

METHOD 1

```
// in header
@interface Book : NSObject {
    NSString *_title;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;

// in implementation
@implementation Book
@synthesize title = _title;
```

METHOD 2

```
// in header
@interface Book : NSObject {
    NSString *title;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;

// in implementation
@implementation Book
@synthesize title;
```

**What are the difference?** I use Method 1 recently, as more tutorials recommend Method 1, but nobody explains why.

Comment: Are you asking about assign vs retain? Or the name of the instance variable being different from the property? There are two differences here.

Comment: Off the track:Can anybody explain me what is the use of using `@synthesize title = _title`.Or what is the use and when do we use  it?Basically what is this doing internally?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is the names.  In #2 the property and instance field have the same name.  In #1 they have different names.

The advantage to #1 is that it's difficult to accidentally reference the property when you mean the instance field or vice-versa.  Referencing the wrong one can lead to having a object retained twice or not retained at all.

The advantage to #2 is that it's marginally simpler, and it works fine if you're careful and a bit formal in your use of things.

[And, I see, one flavor specifies `assign` and the other `retain`, which is a whole different lecture.  You'd not normally use `assign` with an object pointer.]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I mistyped the `assign`. It should be `retain`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I recommend you use `copy` instead of `retain`(and `assign`) for `NSString` type of instance. If it's Mutable, then it gets copied; If not, then it just gets retained.
**Maybe you'll like [THIS DISCUSSION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387959/nsstring-property-copy-or-retain).**

---

And for you question, the difference is that first one use the same name and the second one use the different name for `iVar` & `property`.
Actually, you have a METHOD 3 to use:

```
// in header
@interface Book : NSObject {
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;

// in implementation
@implementation Book
@synthesize title;
```

> For @synthesize to work in the legacy runtime, you must either provide an instance variable with the same name and compatible type of the property or specify another existing instance variable in the @synthesize statement. With the modern runtime, if you do not provide an instance variable, the compiler adds one for you. For example, given the following class declaration and implementation.

Here is a sample code of official doc, you can make it clear( it includes difference between your *METHOD 1* & *METHOD 2*):

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    float sameName;
    float otherName;
}
@property float sameName;
@property float differentName;
@property float noDeclaredIvar;
@end

@implementation MyClass
@synthesize sameName;
@synthesize differentName=otherName;
@synthesize noDeclaredIvar;
@end
```

The compiler for the **legacy runtime** would generate an error at `@synthesize noDeclaredIvar;` whereas the compiler for the **modern runtime** would add an instance variable to represent `noDeclaredIvar`.

> **Note**: iPhone applications and 64-bit programs on Mac OS X v10.5 and later use the modern version of the runtime. Other programs (32-bit programs on Mac OS X desktop) use the legacy version of the runtime. You can refer it [HERE](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtVersionsPlatforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH106)).

However, I suggest to use *METHOD 1* or *METHOD 3*. As you can just use `self.title` in code, the property will help you manage the `alloc` & `release`. If you use *METHOD 2*, you may mix `title` with `self.title`(but `_title` is more clear, uh?). :)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Regarding your answer, is **modern runtime** mean LLVM compiler ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor you're welcome, more detail you can refer it [HERE](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html). And for `Runtime Versions and Platforms`, you can refer it [HERE](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtVersionsPlatforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH106). :)

Comment: Nice links. To conclude, iPhone apps & 64-bit apps are using modern runtime; 32-bit apps are using legacy runtime.

Comment: NSString is one of the object types where it's least useful to use `copy`, since it's invariant.  `copy` only takes additional time and space.

Comment: @HotLicks mum, that's interesting, thank you, I'll take a look at it. :)

Comment: Hi @HotLicks, it's right that `"copy only takes additional time and space"`, but I think may be you'll like [THIS QUESTION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387959/nsstring-property-copy-or-retain). :)