# Strange situation with delegate

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates

Here is my AppDelegate.h(And i have synthesized this properties in Appdelegate.m)

```
{
    NSString *uName;
    NSDictionary *messagesDict;
    NSString *serve1r;
    NSDictionary *firstGet;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (copy, readwrite) NSString *uName;
@property (copy, readwrite) NSString *serve1r;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSDictionary *firstGet;
```

I have tree View controllers, via a textfield i enter some user infos and want to share these objects(username, server IP..) in the other view controllers. 
I assing new variables in the other classes(SecondVC and ThirdVC) like below:

```
MyDelegate *sharedDa= (MyDelegate *)([[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]);
```

After this point, i can see the uName in the second class(log it or display on e textfield) but i cant see anything in the third class. What is wrong with my code can anyone help?

Comment: For instance, in FirstVC i set the username and server as:
sharedData.serve1r=_server.text;
 sharedData.uName=_username.text; but in second class, i cant get the value of the server(i call them as: [sharedDa uName], [sharedDa serve1r]). By doing this, i can get the value of _username.text but the _server.text comes as nil(i mean, [sharedDa serve1r] is empty)

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you set this properties in your view controllers, because with copy property you will use a particular type of setter/getter. (see here: [NSString property: copy or retain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387959/nsstring-property-copy-or-retain) )

I advice you to use (strong, nonatomic), so you will retain always the pointer to the same object. (if, of course - and it should be - the appDelegate instance is always the same)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the other class is not actually importing `MyDelegate.h`

Comment: :) No that is not true. I didn't want to mess people's mind with a lot of code but there isn't any problem with such things

Comment: And i think it is because of copy/readwrite/retain.. something like that. But i cant be sure-and cant realize exactly