# Preprocessor doesn't allow ":" in token in macro to define property

Tags: objective-c, xcode, clang, c-preprocessor, selector

I've created a macro to define a string property

```
#define STRING_PREF(NAME) \
 @property (nonatomic, strong, getter=NAME, setter=set_##NAME##:) NSString * NAME;
```

I try using it thusly:

```
STRING_PREF(username)
```

but end up with the following error:

```
error: pasting formed 'set_username:', an invalid preprocessing token
STRING_PREF(username)
^
foo.h:16:62: note: expanded from macro 'STRING_PREF'
        @property (nonatomic, strong, getter=NAME, setter=set_##NAME##:)        NSString * NAME;
                                                                    ^
1 error generated.
```

Is it not possible to generate selector names with the preprocessor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't paste the `:`, like this:

```
#define STRING_PREF(NAME) @property (nonatomic, copy, getter=NAME, setter=set_##NAME:) NSString *NAME;
```

Also note that strings should be defined as `copy` properties, not `strong`.

Comment: _"strings should be defined as `copy` properties, not `strong`"_ Really? Why? Can't find any documentation suggesting this.

Comment: @QwertyBob simply because `NSString` has a mutable subclass, you never know if you are passed in a Mutable string instead of an immutable one, and the string may change without notice.

Comment: This article explains it well (although it uses the old, pre-ARC retain/release nomenclature): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387959/nsstring-property-copy-or-retain