# How to set value for NSString in another view controller from one viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uistoryboard, ios5.1

I'm using Xcode 4.3.2 & iOS 5.1 simulator, and in my project I am using two View Controllers: testingViewController, and detailView. I want to set values for an NSString in detailView once I didSelect tableViewCell in testingViewController.

For that i used following code:

> testingViewController.h

[image: testingViewController.h]

> testingViewController.m

[image: testingViewController.m]

> detailView.h

[image: detailView.h]

> detailView.m

[image: detailView.m]

I get null values for both `wordName` and `wordMeaning` in the console.

Anyone have a solution? Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a storyboard segue between `testingViewController` and `detailView`, in your `testingViewController`'s `prepareForSegue:` method you should change line

```
detailView *dVw = [[detailView alloc] init];
```

to

```
detailView *dVw = (detailView *)segue.destinationViewController;
```

Also, I recommend you to change in your `detailView.h` file the

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *YOUR_STRING;
```

to

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *YOUR_STRING;
```

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387959/nsstring-property-copy-or-retain

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
[[segue destinationViewController] setWordMeaning:meaningString];
[[segue destinationViewController] setWordName:wordTapped];
```

The problem is that you are creating new object of the `detailView`

Comment: i need one more help, my deployment target iOS 3.0+ so i may not use this segue feature any other code to replace this one so that it'l work on iOS 3.0 + devices. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You can't target for lower version of `iOS` which uses a `Framework` or `API` which is available for higher version of `iOS`

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [this](http://pastebin.com/mNes8SmE) for sharing data between classes. I hope it is useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Set your NSStrings to retain properties, not to assign. Also, when you change their value, always use

```
self.property = ...;
```

in order for the retain to take place. Otherwise, it will be released and you will get null or bad access.

Answer (score 0):

create custom init method

```
declare in .h file 

    -(id)initWithWordName:(NSString*)myWordName andWordMeaning:(NSString*)myWordMeaning;

    and in .m file

    -(id)initWithWordName:(NSString*)myWordName andWordMeaning:(NSString*)myWordMeaning
    {
       self = [super init];
       if(self)
       {
         self.wordName = myWordName;
         self.wordMeaning = myWordMeaning;
       }
       return self;
    }
```

and also NSString property should be copy instead of assign, do change in your detail.h file

Comment: Ya i have done as you mentioned but it's not working again the console displays null Value.

Comment: Inder is correct, in this way it  will create new object of detailView

Comment: Thanks for your reply.i need one more help, my deployment target iOS 3.0+ so i may not use this segue feature any other code to replace this one so that it'l work on iOS 3.0 + devices. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: check this [Link](http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2009/03/uitableview-drill-down-table-view.html)

Comment: Thank you that link 'l help me lot.