# why my app is crashing when the string value is having spaces?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an application in which I am trying to send a string from one view controller to another. It's all working fine when the strings having no spaces. If they do have spaces then the app is crashing with memmory leaks. This is how i am doing it:

```
RegisterViewController2 *register2viewcontroller = [[RegisterViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"RegisterViewController2" bundle:nil];

     register2viewcontroller.username2=[usernamestring retain];
     register2viewcontroller.email2=[emailstring retain];
     register2viewcontroller.password2=[passwordstring retain];
     register2viewcontroller.date=[agestring retain];
     register2viewcontroller.gender2=[gendustring retain];
     register2viewcontroller.occupation2=[occustring retain];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:register2viewcontroller animated:YES];
```

The username2 & usernamestrings are class variables having nonatomic, and strong properties. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Your are probably leak because your properties are also retain the value passed te them, there should be no reason to retain them when you assign a value to them. since you have the properties set to `strong` you should not call retain when you assign them.

Comment: If you have strong properites you are probably using ARC which you shouldn't need to retain.

Comment: if i remove retain then also it is crashing

Comment: 1. What error are you getting? Have you tried explicitly setting all the properties to @"TEST" to see if therein lies the problem?

Comment: -[CFString retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x76c2300

Comment: replace 'retain' with 'copy'.

Answer (score 0):

You should almost never retain strings like that.  If you can show how you are declaring the properties, that would be helpful.

This may also be a useful read: [NSString property: copy or retain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387959/nsstring-property-copy-or-retain)