# Write custom accessor methods in Swift

Tags: swift, core-data, accessor

I would like to override a Core Data dynamically generated accessor method as [can be done in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978563/implementing-custom-accessor-methods).

For instance when a `Team`'s `name` is `nil` return its first `Player`'s `name` instead.

Something like:

```
class Team: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var name: String { // Error: @NSManaged not allowed on computed properties
        get
        {
            self.willAccessValueForKey("name")
            var teamName = self.primitiveValueForKey("name")
            self.didAccessValueForKey("name")

            return teamName ?? (self.players.firstObject as! Player).name
        }
    }
    @NSManaged var breakPoints: NSOrderedSet
    @NSManaged var gamesWon: NSOrderedSet
    @NSManaged var matches: NSOrderedSet
    @NSManaged var matchesWon: NSOrderedSet
    @NSManaged var players: NSOrderedSet
    @NSManaged var pointsWon: NSOrderedSet
    @NSManaged var setsWon: NSOrderedSet
}
```

While keeping the stored values untouched and transparently change the value read by objects accessing the `Team`'s `name` already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not override Core Data accessors in Swift. Instead, create separate computed properties.

```
@NSManaged var actualName: String
var name: String {
 get { 
   self.willAccessValueForKey("actualName")
   let teamName = self.primitiveValueForKey("actualName")
   self.didAccessValueForKey("actualName")

   return teamName ?? (self.players.first as! Player).name
 }
 set {
   name = newValue
   // omitting KVC markers here
   actualName = newValue
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works well using just `"name"` directly and removing `@NSManaged`. Core Data is saving and reading just fine too.

Comment: Not sure if there are any side effects. Please let us know if you encounter any. @Rivera

Comment: I think the side effects are significant, especially regarding performance. You also lose a lot of functionality provided by `@NSManaged`, see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/LifeofaManagedObject.html). I recommend to go with the separate computed property. Alternatively, you can **set** the team name in `awakeFromInsert`.

Comment: Most of the time the team's name must reflect its single player's name, so setting it up will make them out of sync. As for side effects I had none so far and seems like with custom accessors I miss nothing by removing `@NSManaged`: "Core Data dynamically generates efficient public and primitive get and set attribute accessor methods and relationship accessor methods for properties that are defined in the entity of a managed object’s corresponding managed object model".

Comment: If I have a lot attributes like this. It seems like it's a right place for property wrapper. In order to reduce boilerplate code. Is it possible to do this?