# pass a global variable from appdelegate returning null

Tags: ios, objective-c

I set a global variable stores a string value getting from server by socket.
and the socket is impletement in appdelegate as below:

in appdelegate.h:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSStreamDelegate,UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    UITabBarController *tabBarController;
    NSInputStream   *inputStream;
    NSOutputStream  *outputStream;
    NSString *sn,*sn1;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSInputStream *inputStream;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSOutputStream *outputStream;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *sn,*sn1;
```

in appdelegate.m

```
@synthesize  sn,sn1
```

then when incoming socket stream delegate, I set

```
sn=input
 NSLog(@"1st sn: %@",sn);//this sn correct!
```

and then in SecondViewControll.m
I set 
sn1=@"hello";

in FirstViewControll, I impletement as below:
AppDelegate *appDel;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
      appDel = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   NSLog(@"sn1: %@",sn1);;//this sn correct!

LTField.text=appDel.sn; //this one gives error as below, 

}
```

Error is:

```
-[__NSCFSet _isNaturallyRTL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5f87580
2013-06-23 22:49:26.038 test[2987:12c03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet _isNaturallyRTL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5f87580'
```

I dont know why the last line gives error but previous line get correct value?
I guesss it is because the sn is set value inside the delegate, then it doesnt pass out of the deletegate. 
How to pass the correct data to this text field from that stream delegate?

Comment: Looks like a problem with `LTField`.

Comment: no, LTField is working if I set it LTField.text=@"abc";

Comment: You've printed out `sn1`, print out `appDel.sn`, or set a breakpoint and step through with the debugger.

Comment: Which object is `0x5f87580`?  Do you have an `NSCFSet` in `LTField`?

Comment: @meaning-matters how to check which object it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an `NSLog(@"sn: %@", sn);` after your log of `sn1`. It's likely that, after you set `sn = input;`, when that method is complete, `input` goes out of scope. This make `sn` an invalid pointer, and you pass `LTField.text` a null reference. Usually, when you want to keep an `NSString` object passed as an argument, you would use:

```
sn = [input copy];
```

You want to `copy` the input variable since `NSString` is immutable, similar to how you would `retain` a mutable object.

Also, you should change your `@property` declarations to `(nonatomic, copy)` for the `NSString`'s, and then you could use

```
self.sn = input;
```

if you prefer (since using `self` and dot notation calls the setter instead of directly using the variable). See this question for some extra information: [NSString property: copy or retain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387959/nsstring-property-copy-or-retain)