# Passing string to another view not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

```
//FirstViewController.m

#import "EighthViewController.h"

EighthViewController *able = [[EighthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EighthViewController" bundle:nil];
able.extra = @"dd"; //ERROR HERE----------------
[self presentViewController:able animated:YES completion:NULL];

//EighthViewController.h
@interface EighthViewController : UIViewController{
NSString *extra;
}

@property (nonatomic) NSString *extra;
```

Whenever I try and use this code (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)) I get an error in the FirstViewController saying: `Property 'extra' not found on object of type 'EighthViewController *'`

Comment: try [able setExtra:@"dd"]; what does it says?

Comment: Another error "No visible @interface for 'EighthViewController' declares the selector 'setExtra:'"

Comment: how about @synthesize?

Comment: When you're using ARC, then it should look like `@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet NSString *extra;` and you have to add the @synthesize that guitarflow mentioned.

Comment: Note the `IBOutlet` isn't necessary in the property definition for this use case, and `strong` is the default choice (it's implied if you don't specify it). For an NSString, [`copy` may well be a better choice than strong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387959/nsstring-property-copy-or-retain) anyway.

Comment: Does your .h file contain a `@end`?

Comment: I have tried all of your suggestions still the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add that:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *extra;
```

to your `EighthViewController.h` file. And add the following:

```
@synthesize extra;
```

in your `EighthViewController.m` file. Normally it should work then

Hope it helps

Comment: This answer is correct, but `@synthesize` is probably not necessary.