# NSString property and custom init

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, initialization, init, nscopying

I have 2 questions.

**First** - Are string declared as such in obj-c

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *city;
```

Are those `(nonatomic, copy)` right or should I use `(nonatomic, strong)`, or something else ?

**Second** - If I want to set custom initializer for above strings do I use

```
-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)n andCity:(NSString *)c
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.name = n;
        self.city = c;
    }
}
```

or should I use:

```
-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)n andCity:(NSString *)c
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.name = [n copy]
        self.city = [c copy];
    }
}
```

As I can see both ways seem to work for both questions but I'm sure one is more correct than the other, so I wanted to ask which should I use to write correct code in further projects.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - it doesn't really matter if you use `copy` or `strong`. Personally i prefer to copy strings rather than retain them

Second - `

```
-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)n andCity:(NSString *)c

   {
      self = [super init];
       if (self) {
          self.name = n;
          self.city = c;
  }
}`
```

You don't need to use `copy` message once more cause your properties will copy n and c. If you apply your second piece of code you'll copy n and c twice and have a memory leak

Comment: It very much does matter if you use `copy` vs. `strong`. Use `strong` and I can pass you an instance of `NSMutableString` and then change it out from under you after the fact. This is why value semantic properties should always be `copy`. Immutable objects will implement `-copyWithZone:` by doing `return [self retain];` so as to not actually create a second copy when it's not needed.

Answer (score 13):

You want to use `copy` for value-semantic-typed properties. (Of which `NSString` is always one.) Otherwise, I can pass you an instance of `NSMutableString` and then change it out from under you after the fact. Immutable objects will implement `-copyWithZone:` by doing `return [self retain]`; so as to not actually create a second copy when it's not needed. See also: [NSString property: copy or retain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387959/nsstring-property-copy-or-retain?rq=1)

In terms of your `-init` method, you want to avoid using the property setters like you have since they could be overridden in a subclass to do something unforeseeable by your class. So assuming default auto-ivar-synthesis naming pattern, you would want to do this:

```
-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)n andCity:(NSString *)c
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        _name = [n copy];
        _city = [c copy];
    }
    return self;
}
```

It's a subtle thing, and it won't often be a problem, but if you continue to use inherently-virtual property setters in `-init` and `-dealloc` methods, over a long enough timeline, you *will* get burned by this (can you tell I've been burned by this?)

As for leaked memory, if you're using ARC, doing something like `self.foo = [bar copy];` when foo is a `copy` property *will* result in copy getting called twice, and potentially two copies being made, but ARC should take care of properly releasing the redundant/intermediate copy, and there should *not* be a memory leak.