# change property object will not affect property

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to verify something that I always use but when I think about it ... I get confused why it worked that way and I sure I read the explanation about it but I cant find it.
As far as I understand apple create their setter as something like this.

```
-(void)setString:(NSString *)value {
   if (_string != value) {
      [_string release];
      _string = [value retain];
   }
}
```

Now usually I create properties like this.

```
@property (nonatomic) NSString *string;
@synthesize string = _string;
```

The question is about next code:

```
        NSString *s = @"Should be deleted";
        [self setString:s];
        NSLog(@"string check111 =%@",self.string);
        s = NULL;
        NSLog(@"string check222=%@",self.string);
```

The same output will be generated. From the setter I can see that my property points on the object that I changed but the property value will be the same.That situation triggers another question (if it works like that why would I need *copy* attribute). 
Can someone provide a short explanation about it? (or concrete link to read).
Tnx A Lot. (I think my question may be already asked in the forum )

Comment: You assertion that "string 's' should be deleted" is wrong in the first place. Just setting a reference to NULL has nothing to do with deallocation of the object it points.

Comment: You are all right,if I had a chance I would delete that stupid question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has no effect because you are changing the object to which `s` points to.

This diagram probably explains it better, originally you have something like this:

[image]

Changing the point of `s` will not affect `_string`.

[image]

The idea of setting the property to copy is in case you set your string property to a mutable string and then change the content of it. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387959/nsstring-property-copy-or-retain).

Comment: Yes, you totally right I don't what I was thinking about when posting that kind of question.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it would be something like this

```
    NSString *s = @"Should be deleted"; // create autoreleased string
    [self setString:s]; // retain string
    NSLog(@"string check111 =%@",self.string);
    s = NULL; // reset pointer value to null. This operation doesn't affect string object
    NSLog(@"string check222=%@",self.string);
    // string's retain counter will be decreased by autorelease pool later
```