# How can i hold the value of a string when the viewController goes to another tableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue

Well, that question sure sounds weird but i couldn't find a better way to put it.

I m pretty sure its a basic mistake but i m stuck.

I got a main home view controller, there are 2 buttons which leads to 2 different tableViewController.

i will use both of the selections.

But when i get the selected index from one table view and go the the next one, the first one's value become null.

```
if (tempFromLocationString!=NULL) {
    //tempFromLocationString=@"asd";
    fromLocationLabel.text=tempFromLocationString;
}
if (tempToLocationString!=NULL) {
    toLocationLabel.text=tempToLocationString;
}
```

this is how i segue from tableView to View controller

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"fromLocationSegue"])
    {

         NSLog(@"%@",selectionString);
ViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc.tempFromLocationString=selectionString;


}
}
```

and this is how i get the selected cell's value.

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


   selectionString=[fromLocationArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"%@",selectionString);


}
```

this is my code. i get temp strings with segues and i m applying these codes in view did load.

all the NSStrings declared in .h files.

the flow is like this;

user enter the app,
select a button,
goes to the first table view controller
select a location,
clicks ok button and goes back to the first view controller with segue ( selectionString)
the label is set to the selectionString appropriately

user click next button,
goes to the select table view
select a location 
clicks ok and goes back the first view controller now the second label is set to the selectionString appropriately but now the first one is deleted and the string become null

Comment: can you edit your post to be more clear and to add more code?

Comment: a more precise explanation would help. Can you please explain the flow

Comment: how the tempFromLocationString property is declared?

Comment: How are you going back after the first table view selection has been made?

Comment: user clicks ok button and segue starts with the identifier @Wain

Comment: @mxb 

property (strong, nonatomic)  NSString *tempFromLocationString;
property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *tempToLocationString;

Comment: maybe you could try @property (copy)

Comment: @mxb can you elaborate a little bit, never heard of it

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387959/nsstring-property-copy-or-retain

Comment: So you are triggering a new segue, or you are unwinding a segue (this is a very important distinction)

Comment: triggering a new segue @Wain

Comment: Then the answer from @iphonic explains the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK
Your app flow

**Case1**

1. User enter the app **- Correct**
2. Select a button **- Correct**
3. Goes to the First TableViewController select a location **-
       Correct**
4. Clicks ok button **- Correct**
5. and Goes back to the first view controller with segue
       (selectionString) the label is set to the selectionString
       appropriately - **Incorrect**

   **Step 5** is incorrect, why?

   **Answer -** Because you are again pushing the `ViewController` after the selection in tableViewController, where as your `ViewController` already exist in the stack, so here instead of using segue, you should just pop the viewcontroller with same reference taken from ViewController.

**Case2**

1. User click next button - **Correct**
2. Goes to the select table view select a location clicks ok - **Correct**
3. and goes back the first view controller now the second label is set to the selectionString appropriately but now the first one is deleted and the string become null - **Incorrect**

**Step 3** is incorrect the same way as **Case1**.

**Answer-** Again you are actually not going back, you are going forward, so what happens is you are creating a new instance of ViewController on selection, which doesn't have the previous selected value.

**Solution**

1. Create `NSString` property in each respective tableViewController separately same as you have in `ViewController`.
2. When you segue tableViewController from ViewController, assign the property like

   ```
     TableViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
     vc.tempFromLocationString=self.tempFromLocationString;
   ```
3. On selection in tableviewcontroller do the following

   ```
     self.tempFromLocationString=selectionString;
     [self.navigationController popViewController:YES];
   ```
4. Now instead of assigning value in `ViewDidLoad` in `ViewController`, do it in `ViewWillAppear`.

I hope it helps.

Comment: i wasn't doing any segue process in view controller thats what i will try right now.Gonna let you know but thanks so much for your effort

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your strings are not NULL when you set your labels.

Try to put a breakpoint before those lines, and check your temp strings

```
if (tempFromLocationString!=NULL) {
    //tempFromLocationString=@"asd";
    fromLocationLabel.text=tempFromLocationString;
}
if (tempToLocationString!=NULL) {
    toLocationLabel.text=tempToLocationString;
}
```

If they are not NULL try this:

```
if (tempFromLocationString && [tempFromLocationString length] > 0) {
    fromLocationLabel.text=tempFromLocationString;
}
```