# loosing string property after setting base64encoded string

Tags: objective-c, properties, nsstring

I have an object of class A which has a property of NSString.
I am setting this property with a Base64 encoded String.
Once I set another property, the first property changes to nil

How can that be?

Here is my code: 
A.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* b64ImageData;
```

Here I am setting it:

```
[imageInfo setB64ImageData:string64encoded];
[imageInfo setName:last];
```

Note that the imageInfo class resides in a library using Manual Reference Counting, while the code resides in a project with Automatic Reference Counting.

See screenshot of debugger before setting other property:
[image: screenshot of debugger before setting other property]

See screenshot after setting other property:
[image: screenshot after setting other property]

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: An `NSString` property is supposed to be declared as `copy` rather than `retain`.

Comment: changed it to ` copy` but same effect. :-(

Comment: Is `name` just a property or is `setName` implemented?

Comment: found the error and fixed it. Had nothing todo with my code but with the library. Thanks for help.

Comment: @vadian, there is nothing wrong with `retain` `NSString` property.

Comment: @Cy-4AH No, it's not wrong, but the semantics of classes based on constants like `NSString` and `NSNumber` are to copy the value rather than to retain it.

Comment: @vadian why copy `NSNumber`? You can't mutate it.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387959/nsstring-property-copy-or-retain/388002#388002